# ASP.NET MVC store CSS class in the node

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mvcsitemapprovider

I would like to add icons from Font Awesome to my sitemap. I want to store related classes in my node and then, in my `menuHelperMode.cshtml` assign this class to related place holder:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Documents" controller="Documents" action="Index" iconClass ="fa fa-file-text"/>
```

From what i have seen so far, i assume it can work, however i can't find a method how can i access this custom node in my `.cshtml` file. I have tried this (as mentioned in related question):

```
<div class="@("circle " + child["iconClass"])">
```

But it can not be indexed like `[""]` here. I think, it works for binding events only. So my question is, how can i access my custom node attribute directly from `cshtml` Razor layout?

Comment: What is the "child" instance of? MvcSiteMapNode?

Comment: @Andrei It is instance of `SiteMapNodeModel` class. I am using foreach to list through the `MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.MenuHelperModel`.

Comment: Then I think it is as simple as `child.Attributes["iconClass"]`

Comment: @Andrei i can update my question and add all code from my MenuHelperModel.cshtml, but is it really necessary?

Comment: @Andrei it works, however i am getting error if node does not have this attribute. There is a way to check it, before retrieving it's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes of the node can be accessed via Attributes property:

```
if (child.Attributes.ContainsKey("iconClass"))
{
    <div class="@("circle " + child.Attributes["iconClass"])">
}
else
{
    <div class="circle">
}
```